# Compare today day and shop opening days and show if opened or closed?

Tags: php

Hi I'm trying to create a function in php that checks the current day and return if the store is open or closed. This is what I have so far, it works but it's very long so if anyone knows shortest path then please help !

```
$today = date('w'); // today 

$starting = "THUR"; //opening day
$closing = "MON"; //closing day


$openday = date("w", strtotime($starting));  //coverting to number 
$closeday = date("w", strtotime($closing));  // coverting to number 


//checking if closing day is greater than opening day 

if($openday < $closeday ){ 

    //checking if today lies between starting and closing day

      if($today > $openday && $today <= $closeday ){ 
        
        $stat = 'Opened';  //if today lies between starting day and ending day then Opened
      }
      else{  
        $stat = 'Closed'; //else Closed
      }
}

// if closing day is less than opening day 
else{  

  //checking if today lies between opening day and friday
  if($today > $openday && $today <= 6){ 

    $stat = 'Opened';   

  }
  //checking if today lies between sunday and closeday
  else if( $today > 0 &&  $today <= $closeday ){   

    $stat = 'Opened';    

  }
  else{
    $stat = 'Closed';  // else Closed
  }
}
```

This returns if day lies between Thursday and Monday Opened else Closed. If you know short way to do then please help me

Answer (score 1):

If you know the days when you are closed ( which you must do ) why not something like this?

```
    $closed=array(
        date('w',strtotime('Tuesday')),
        date('w',strtotime('Wednesday'))
    );
    $status=in_array( date('w'),$closed ) ? 'Closed' : 'Open';
    printf('We are "%s" on %s', $status, date('l') );
```

which today outputs:

```
We are "open" on Saturday
```